# Prevent aurelia-dialog from closing

Tags: aurelia

Hi I can get a basic dialog running but I would like to keep the dialog up and close it myself. Is that possible ?

Currently clicking on the OK button immedately removes the dialog.

Basically I want the dialog as a login box with a username / password. On failed log-in attemts I would like to display an error message on the dialog and not close it.

My template is

```
<template>
  <ai-dialog>
    <ai-dialog-header>
    </ai-dialog-header>
    <ai-dialog-body>
      <h2>Username:</h2>
      <input value.bind="auth.username" attach-focus="true" />
      <br />
      <h2>Password:</h2>
      <input value.bind="auth.password" attach-focus="false" />
      <br /><br />
      <span innerhtml.bind="auth.error">No Error</span>
    </ai-dialog-body>
    <ai-dialog-footer>
      <button click.trigger="controller.ok(auth)">Ok</button>
    </ai-dialog-footer>
  </ai-dialog>
</template>
```

and the model

```
import {DialogController} from 'aurelia-dialog';

export class Login {
  static inject = [DialogController];
  auth = { username: '', password: '', error: '' };

  constructor(private controller : DialogController){

    this.controller = controller;
  }

  activate(auth){
    this.auth = auth;
  }
}
```

I am calling from another module like

```
let auth = { username: 'Wade', password: 'Watts', error : ""};

  this.dialogService.openAndYieldController({viewModel: Login, model: auth}).then(controller => {
    // Note you get here when the dialog is opened, and you are able to close dialog  
    // Promise for the result is stored in controller.result property

   controller.result.then((response) => {

      if (!response.wasCancelled) {
        console.log('good');
      } else {
        console.log('bad');
      }

      console.log(response);

    })

  });
```

Thanks

Comment: use `openAndYieldController()` (https://github.com/aurelia/dialog#getting-access-to-dialogcontroller-api-outside)

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried using openAndYieldController. I have edited the question.

Comment: Which view are you loading inside of your dialog? You should be able to control this through the viewmodel inside of your dialog.

Comment: I haven't seen your view, but I think you're probably using the ai-dialog footer element, right? If so, that element has predefined behavior. You can opt not to use it and implement that behavior yourself. If this is what you're doing, I'll post a detailed answer for this case scenario.

Comment: Thanks I am using  ai-dialog-footer. I have updated my question to show the code.

Comment: Disregard the stuff about `ai-dialog-footer` - I was working under an incorrect assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible - and quite simple, actually. The solution here is not to use `controller.ok()` or `controller.cancel()` until (or unless) you want to close the dialog.

In your case, I'm not entirely sure why you're calling `controller.ok()` from your button, but you could do something like this:

```
<ai-dialog-footer>
  <button click.trigger="tryLogin(auth)">Ok</button>
</ai-dialog-footer>
```

...and in your viewModel:

```
import {DialogController} from 'aurelia-dialog';

export class Login {
  static inject = [DialogController];
  auth = { username: '', password: '', error: '' };

  constructor(private controller : DialogController){

    this.controller = controller;
  }

  activate(auth){
    this.auth = auth;
  }

  tryLogin (auth) {
    myLoginService.login(auth)
      .then((success) => {
        if (success) this.controller.ok(auth);
      });
  }
}
```

I hope that makes sense. Essentially, the view in your modal is just another Aurelia view and viewmodel pair - it's no different than any other view in your application. The `controller.ok()` and `.cancel()` methods are designed to close the dialog and return control to the caller. However, as long as you're inside the dialog, you can do anything you could do elsewhere in the application.

Comment: Great! It makes perfect sense after seeing it. Thanks